# import tensorflow giving error in windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using a 64 bit windows OS and I successfully installed tensorflow but on importing it in python 3.6 , I am getting the following error.
Please tell how to fix this.

> import tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: What version of tensorflow do you have currently? Have you installed the python library using pip?

Comment: i am using 1.12.0 version of tensorflow, when i tried to degrade it , import worked but tflearn import gave some error that "tensorflow.contrib" not found